# DRY method to add a class to <body> in the base template?

Tags: django, django-templates

This is the general structure of my `base.html`:

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>

    <body class="noscroll">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-static-top navbar-dark bg-inverse">
        </nav>
        {% block content %}
        {% endblock content %}
    </body>
</html>
```

On certain pages, I want the `noscroll` class which is essentially `overflow-y: hidden;` but I also have pages that require the scroll. I could move the navbar into its own snippet and insert that, but such a method seems unsatisfactory. Or I could make a separate `base_noscroll.html`, but that may lead to inconsistencies, so I would have to nest two templates which again would become unsatisfactory.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just add an override-able block with the default content:

```
<body class="{% block body_class %}noscroll{% endblock %}">
```

then the `noscroll` class is there, or you can override it in a template that extends `base.html`. Django template blocks can go nearly anywhere; they don't have to wrap entire HTML tags.

If you find yourself overriding this block a lot, you can always just add another template that extends `base.html` and does the override, then extend that:

```
# noscroll.html

{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block body_class %}{# empty to override #}{% endblock %}
```

Then in subsequent pages you can extend either template. How much flexibility you need is always up to you.

Comment: If this block is empty, is time still spent processing it? I know it's not much, but it's enough for Django to write in their docs that `block`'s are more efficient than `include`'s: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/performance/#template-performance

Comment: Yes, there will still be processing time. Alternatively, you could pass in the css class value in the template context, but that could get highly repetitive.

Comment: Out of all these options, which do you think would be best?

Comment: I work on very large projects like National Geographic Channel, and this is what we do.